# Java не заходит в блок catch

Tags: java, многопоточность, парсер, исключения, runtime

Я хочу обработать 2 файла через tika. Я использую

```
//Pool threads
serviceOne = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

И задачи закидываю в него так:

```
System.out.println("Текущий файл идет на обработку: " + file.getName());
serviceOne.submit(new Task(fileDat));
```

вот код:

```
(Код из - static class Task implements Runnable из метода run)

try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr))){
                
                String mimeType = tika.detect(is); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
                metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType
                
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); //create xml-парсер
                ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
              
                parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc); //разбор файла на части


} catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex ) {

...

}
```

Файл считывается в объект is, затем доходит до строчки pasrer.parse, потом снова переходит на строчку try(), а потом переходит в файл FutureTask.java (это не мой файл, а из другой библиотеки). И в этом файле бросает какое-то exception,

```
public void run() {
        if (state != NEW ||
            !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                         null, Thread.currentThread()))
            return;
        try {
            Callable<V> c = callable;
            if (c != null && state == NEW) {
                V result;
                boolean ran;
                try {
                    result = c.call();
                    ran = true;
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    result = null;
                    ran = false;
                    setException(ex);
                }
                if (ran)
                    set(result);
            }
```

Это наверное - Throwable ex, похоже на RuntimeException. Потом получается что после моего try() мы не переходим в мой catch, а просто на вход is поступает новый второй файл, а старый будто проглатываем. Будто мы ловим exception в run и он пропускает первый файл и начинает брать второй новый файл.

---

Подскажите как обработать такой Throwable ex? Или как мне попасть в мой catch, а потом выполнить код ниже него. Просто получается так: мы обрабатываем первый файл, не можем его обработать и просто пропускаем его и начинаем обработку нового файла. Подскажите как быть?

---

Пробовал:

```
} catch (Throwable th){

System.out.println(th.getMessage());
                
th.printStackTrace();
```

Выводит:

```
org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:131)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:263)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:231)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:80)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:353)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.<init>(FontMapperImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMappers$DefaultFontMapper.<clinit>(FontMappers.java:36)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMappers.instance(FontMappers.java:46)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.<init>(PDTrueTypeFont.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:146)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:933)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:515)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:489)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:144)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:397)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:125)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.processPages(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:967)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:272)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:96)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
    at com.mycompany.stackexp.Parser$Task.run(Parser.java:479)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: у тебя библиотека `slf4j` не той версии, что используется `fontbox`ом, поэтому когда фонтбокс хочет записать что-то в лог, он не находит метод `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V` и падает

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку. Подскажите пожалуйста, как понять какая нужна версия slf4j? Я например сейчас использую версию 1.7.30.

Comment: Если используешь Мавен, то `mvn dependency:tree`. Если не используешь, то найди репозиторий этого фонтбокса и посмотри, какую версию они прописали в зависимости.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr))){
   //blah-blah
} catch (Throwable th) {
     th.printStacktrace(); //хотя бы, чтобы понять, что у вас за ошибка
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, исправил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, лог ошибки получен, дальше разбирайтесь или задавайте новый вопрос :)